# Most efficient way to implement this logic in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

The problem is as follows. Let there be two types of orders, VE and VC orders (VE orders have priority over VC orders). And two types of priorities HIGH and LOW. Every order is identified by an ORDER_ID, then labeled with an order type and lastly a priority. It happens that over time orders can improve their type, priority, or both, resulting in several new entries with duplicate order id's. The task is to label the state with the highest priority for each order with 1 and the rest with 0's. How would you attempt to do this considering that the ORDERS table is sufficiently big and that in some cases some rows would have to be re-labeled.

Example input:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you get duplicate order IDs? That's the problem you need to fix. Then you don't need to implement that strange labeling scheme.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

> "How would you attempt to do this considering that the ORDERS table is
>   sufficiently big "

Well, first of all I wouldn't query all the rows in a "sufficiently big" table.  That's why Nature gave us the WHERE clause.

So, given some form of filtering, the remaining logic is:

```
select order_id
       , order_type
       , priority
       , case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end as temp_label
 from
       (  select order_id
                 , order_type
                 , priority
                 , row_number() over ( partition by order_id
                                       order by decode(order_type, 'VE', 1, 2)
                                                , decode(priority, 'HIGH', 1, 2)
                                       ) as rn
           from your_table
           where whatever = 'BLAH' -- your criteria go here
        )
```